# Piping echo, tail and sed leads to wrong output

Tags: bash, sed, echo, tail, piping

I want to add an entry in `fstab` and I'm using this command in my `/bin/bash` script:

```
echo -n | tail -1 /mnt/etc/fstab | sed 's/\(-\).*/-03/' >> /mnt/etc/fstab
echo -e -n "\t" >> /mnt/etc/fstab  
echo -n "/home" >> /mnt/etc/fstab
echo -e -n "\t" >> /mnt/etc/fstab  
echo -n "ext4" >> /mnt/etc/fstab
echo -e -n "\t" >> /mnt/etc/fstab  
echo -n "default,noatime" >> /mnt/etc/fstab 
echo -e -n "\t" >> /mnt/etc/fstab  
echo -n "0" >> /mnt/etc/fstab 
echo -e -n "\t" >> /mnt/etc/fstab  
echo "2" >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

this is the original content:

```
proc                  /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=ee397c53-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=ee397c53-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
```

and this is the expected output:

```
proc                  /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=ee397c53-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=ee397c53-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
PARTUUID=ee397c53-03  /home           ext4    defaults,noatime  0       2
```

instead the output is the following:

```
proc                  /proc           proc    defaults          0       0
PARTUUID=ee397c53-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2
PARTUUID=ee397c53-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1
PARTUUID=ee397c53-03
    /home   ext4    default,noatime 0   2
```

What's wrong in the piping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is off. You are piping `echo -n` to `tail`. `echo -n` produces no output so you are piping nothing to tail.

You could append the output of your `tail | sed` command using `echo -n` instead:

```
echo -n $(tail -1 /mnt/etc/fstab | sed 's/\(-\).*/-03/') >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Wrapping the `tail | sed` bit into `$()` allows echo to take the stdout of those commands and echo out the results (without the line feed as desired) back into fstab.

Alternatively you could use `xargs` to pipe TO echo so it can read from stdin.

```
tail -1 /mnt/etc/fstab | sed 's/\(-\).*/-03/' | xargs echo -n >> /mnt/etc/fstab
```

Also, you could use `printf` to do the whole script:

```
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $(tail -1 /etc/fstab | sed 's/\(-\).*/-03/') "/home" "ext4" "default,noatime" "0" "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Following also may help you in same.

```
awk -F'[- ]' 'END{val=sprintf("%02d",$2+1);print $1"-"val," /home           ext4    defaults,noatime  0       2"}'   Input_file
```

If you are happy with above awk's result then you could save results with following command too.

```
awk -F'[- ]' '1;END{val=sprintf("%02d",$2+1);print $1"-"val," /home           ext4    defaults,noatime  0       2"}' Input_file  > tmp && mv tmp Input_file
```